# iptables rule to match address suffix

Tags: reverse, mask, iptables, rule, cidr

I'm going to build connection load balancer, which will select route depending on last bits of destination address. It means I need a rule which will work as reversed CIDR. Is there any extension to iptables with will have such functionality ?

Comment: This would be a better question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

The --dst filter allows you to specify the netmask in dotted decimal notation (i.e. without the CIDR numeric prefix length shorthand). Here's a rule that will log all packets that go to a host with a destination address ending in 127:

```
iptables -I FORWARD --dst 0.0.0.127/0.0.0.255 -j LOG
```